# Convert a single page pdf to double page

Tags: pdf, conversion, page

I have a PDF document that is laid out such that each individual page is its own page, like:

```
--------
|      |
|      |
|  1   |
|      |
|      |
--------

--------
|      |
|      |
|  2   |
|      |
|      |
--------

--------
|      |
|      |
|  3   |
|      |
|      |
--------
```

etc.

I am wondering how I could make it so that the pdf itself, without using a tool to modify the PDF's view like Acrobat, have two side by side pages, like:

```
--------  --------
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
|  1   |  |  2   |
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
--------  --------

--------  --------
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
|  3   |  |  4   |
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
--------  --------

--------  --------
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
|  5   |  |  6   |
|      |  |      |
|      |  |      |
--------  --------
```

I would like to do this so it permanently modifies the PDF. I am on macOS Monterey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could simply print it to a PDF using the built in virtual printer. In print settings select two pages per side like explained [here](https://www.techbout.com/print-two-pages-per-sheet-on-mac-23006/)

Comment: If you want to process many files, you may want to have a look into imagemagick

Comment: @mashuptwice Great answer, I didn't even think of this! Appreciate it!

Comment: Well, I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply print it to a PDF using the built in virtual printer.

In the print settings you set "Pages per Sheet" to "2" like explained [here](https://www.techbout.com/print-two-pages-per-sheet-on-mac-23006/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem witht that is, that it has no side-to-side printing, here's a better solution as an AppleScript (for Macs). It enlarges every (un)even page to twice the width and places the follow-up page as a watermark on that area. If you want the first page to remain single, choose "With Cover":

on open dropped_file

```
set file_path to POSIX path of dropped_file

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ".pdf"
set convert_path to every text item of file_path
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_doublesided.pdf"
set save_path to convert_path as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

tell application "Adobe Acrobat"
    
    activate
    
    open file_path
    
    set page_count to number of pages of document 1
    
    tell page 2
        
        set page_cbox to crop box
        
        set new_value_1 to 1st item of page_cbox as integer
        set new_value_2 to 2nd item of page_cbox as integer
        set old_value_3 to 3rd item of page_cbox as integer
        set new_value_4 to 4th item of page_cbox as integer
        set new_value_3 to (2 * old_value_3)
        
    end tell
    
    
    set cover_type to button returned of (display dialog "Bitte wählen:" buttons {"Without Cover", "With Cover"} default button 2)
    
    
    if cover_type is false then
        
        error number -128 (* user cancelled *)
        
    else if cover_type is equal to "With Cover" then
        
        set loop_start to 1
        set loop_end to ((page_count - 1) / 2 - 0.5) as integer
        
    else if cover_type is equal to "Without Cover" then
        
        set loop_start to 0
        set loop_end to ((page_count) / 2 - 0.5) as integer
        
    end if
    
    repeat with actual_page from loop_start to loop_end - 1
        
        set script_set_media to "this.setPageBoxes('Media'," & actual_page & "," & actual_page & ",[" & new_value_1 & "," & new_value_2 & "," & new_value_3 & "," & new_value_4 & "]);"
        set script_set_crop to "this.setPageBoxes('Crop'," & actual_page & "," & actual_page & ",[" & new_value_1 & "," & new_value_2 & "," & new_value_3 & "," & new_value_4 & "]);"
        set script_set_bleed to "this.setPageBoxes('Bleed'," & actual_page & "," & actual_page & ",[" & new_value_1 & "," & new_value_2 & "," & new_value_3 & "," & new_value_4 & "]);"
        set script_set_trim to "this.setPageBoxes('Trim'," & actual_page & "," & actual_page & ",[" & new_value_1 & "," & new_value_2 & "," & new_value_3 & "," & new_value_4 & "]);"
        set script_set_art to "this.setPageBoxes('Art'," & actual_page & "," & actual_page & ",[" & new_value_1 & "," & new_value_2 & "," & new_value_3 & "," & new_value_4 & "]);"
        
        set script_add_watermark to "this.addWatermarkFromFile({cDIPath: this.path, nSourcePage: " & actual_page + 1 & ", nStart: " & actual_page & ", nEnd: " & actual_page & ", nHorizAlign: 0, nVertAlign: 0, nHorizValue: " & old_value_3 & ", nVertValue: 0, nOpacity: 1, nRotation: 0, bOnTop: true});"
        
        
        set script_this_delete to "this.deletePages(" & actual_page + 1 & "," & actual_page + 1 & ");"
        
        do script script_set_media
        do script script_set_crop
        do script script_set_bleed
        do script script_set_trim
        do script script_set_art
        delay 0.5
        do script script_add_watermark
        delay 0.5
        do script script_this_delete
        
    end repeat
    
    save active doc to save_path
    
    close active doc saving no
    
end tell
```

end open